# Automated/Continuous testing with MonoDevelop

Tags: mono, monodevelop, continuous-testing

By following the instructions about automating unit tests using [Mighty moose](http://continuoustests.com) for stand alone clients (MonoDevelop IDE), I understood it was possible. There is a section on 
*How can I get Mighty Moose working natively on my mac?* on their support page.

Has anyone had success with it? I either see Mighty moose detecting file changes forever or throwing an unhandled exception.

Regards

Shaun